# odoo how to show the values of my two fields once I do a select

Tags: odoo

I have two models:

- `medical.lab.test.type`

This is my class:

```html
class MedicalLabTestType(models.Model):
    _name = "medical.lab.test.type"
    _description = "Medical Lab Test Types"
    name = fields.Char(
        'Test',
        help='Name of test type, such as X-Ray, Hemogram, Biopsy, etc.',
        required=True,
    )
    code = fields.Char(
        'Code',
        size=128,
        help='Short name or code for test type.',
        required=True,
    )
    description = fields.Text('Description')

    Test_Prix = fields.Float(
        string='Price of the test',
        required=True,
    )
    Nbr_days = fields.Integer(
        string='Number of days to have results',
        required=True,
    )
```

and

- `medical.lab`

This is my class:

```html
class MedicalLab(models.Model):
    _name = 'medical.lab'
    _description = "Medical Labs"


    test_type_id = fields.Many2one(
        string='Test Type',
        comodel_name='medical.lab.test.type',
        help='Lab test type.',
    )


    physician_id = fields.Many2one(
        string='Pathologist',
        comodel_name='medical.physician',
        help='Pathologist that performed the exam.',
    )
    request_physician_id = fields.Many2one(
        string='Requesting Physician',
        comodel_name='medical.physician',
        help='Physician that requested the exam.',
    )
```

The problem is to show on the view the value of `Test_Prix` and `Nbr_days` once I choose a Test

How should i proceed?, should I use an onchange function!!!

Comment: Use `onchange` function  to load the values and let users to edit/change them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to show field of selected m2o on the current view you should use 
related field.

in your `midecal.lab` model add:

```py
# related field should always keep the same type Foalt Float, Char Char
# and it's recommended that you put readonly because if you edit 
# the value the value will be edited in the related record when you save
Test_Prix = fields.Float(
 retlated='test_type_id.Test_Prix',
 readonly=True
)

Nbr_days = fields.Integer(
    retlated='test_type_id.Nbr_days',
    readonly=True
)
```

and now you can add this two field to you view like

> NB: related field are not stored in database they work as proxy if you
>   want to create the field in the database use `store=True`

EDITS :

use onchange not compute field is computed

```py
date_perform = fields.Datetime( string='Date of Results', )

@api.onchange('date_request', 'Nbr_days') 
def _compute_date_result(self): 
    for record in self: 
        business_days_to_add = record.Nbr_days 
        current_date = fields.Datetime.from_string(record.date_request) 
        .....
```

Comment: Yes we need it you know. Thank you

Comment: how can I evaluate the value of a field in order to change another field value, when i click save button ?

Comment: you mean compute a field based on other fields

Comment: now I have two fields notes and state, the default value of state is draft. what i need is to change the state field value to in progree when the notes field value is != empty, when I click save button

Comment: And before saving it's oky to change the value in UI. If yes you need to use onchange. Or override the write method if you dont want to change the value untill the user hits save.  So do want to keep the value always draft until it's saved or when he write slle thing tge value change in real time and if he delete the satete return to draft

Comment: is there any possibility to change manually a computed field?

Comment: Only if you remove readonly And nothing in the view will trigger the compute but what is the point

Comment: I have a field date_result that it depends on two other fields: date_request and nbr_days. what i need is that the compute works but also give me the possibility to change it manually if i want. if i remove readonly they give the possibility to change it but once i hit save the old value(by compute) is here

Comment: `date_perform = fields.Datetime(
        string='Date of Results',
        compute='_compute_date_result',
        readonly=False,
    )

    @api.depends('date_request', 'Nbr_days')
    def _compute_date_result(self):
       
        for record in self:
            business_days_to_add = record.Nbr_days
            current_date = fields.Datetime.from_string(record.date_request)
            .....`